# Substitution option: s in sed command

Tags: sed

I am using sed command make substitution in the file.
Assume my file1 is:

```
10
11
10
11
```

Then I want to substitute the 1st "10" in file1 to "12", and dump to file2. The file2 should be:

```
12
11
10
11
```

I tried this command:

```
sed 's/10/12/' file1 >file2
```

But it changed the 2nd "10" also. So, how can I write the sed command to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use awk instead of sed, you can have more control like this:

```
awk '!changed && /10/ { sub(/10/, "12"); changed = 1}1' file1
12
11
10
11
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sed '0,/10/s/10/12/' file1 >file2
```

Comment: This will do the job, but you should explain what it does and why it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Like GriffinG said, you can do something like this:

```
sed '0,/10/ s/10/12/' file1 > file2
```

The `0,/10/` at the beginning sets the bounds on the following substitution command. It says start from line 0 (the first line), and go until a line it matches the pattern `/10/`. So After that first match, `sed` will stop processing that substitution.

Comment: `0,/.../` is GNU sed only

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have GNU `sed`, try:

```
echo | cat - file | sed '1,/10/s/10/12/; 1d'
```

or

```
sed '1,/10/s/10/12/; 1d' << EOF

$(cat file)
EOF
```

or in `bash` / `ksh93`

```
sed '1,/10/s/10/12/; 1d' <(echo; cat file)
```

GNU sed knows `0,/10/` so the extra empty line is not required